# cann't install libjpeg.so.62

Tags: 12.04

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to install FSLview software:

http://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/

But I get an issue when installing third script,

```
libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, I cannot used `sudo apt-get install libjpeg62`,there is no internet connect.

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `libjpeg62`, `libjpeg62-dbg`, `libjpeg62-dev` and `libc6`. These can be downloaded from http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/

Write down or print the following Links. Go to a internet cafe and download the .deb files. Bring them and copy them to a folder. Move to that folder by `cd [folder directory]` and install with :

```
sudo dpkg -i [FILE NAME].deb
```

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/libjpeg62

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/libc6

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/libjpeg62-dbg

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/libjpeg62-dev

**Other method :**

You can copy them to `/var/cache/apt/archives` with `sudo cp [FOLDEER DIRECTORY]/[FILENAME.DEB] /var/cache/apt/archives`.

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dbg libjpeg62-dev libc6
```

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` can [create a list of all packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/PrintUris) you need to download in order to install `libjpeg62` and its dependencies. Have it create the list, download the packages and install them using `dpkg`.

To create the list, issue

```
apt-get --print-uris --yes install libjpeg62 | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 > packages.txt
```

Then, take the resulting `packages.txt` to another computer, download the packages from the URLs in that file and copy them into an empty directory on your offline computer.

Once you've done so, you can install all the needed packages by opening a terminal, changing into the directory you've saved the packages in and issueing

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```